# Upgrading from jboss logging to log4j 2.17.1 is this version compatable

Tags: log4j, wildfly-swarm

Where can we check the log4j version 2.17.1 compatibility with wilfly 10 server

Comment: What do you mean? WildFly 10 does not use or include log4j 2.

Comment: Wildfly uses default jobss default logging how can we change it to log4j latest version I have also check wildfly 10 how to do blog how can we upgrade to log4j 2.x in wildfly server any help here

Comment: You can't get WildFly to use log4j itself. However, if you include log4j 2 in your deployment you can get your deployment to use log4j 2.